# Add a custom ID to a cloned HTML node using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML which is cloned with JavaScript...

```
<tr class="empty-row screen-reader-text">
    <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">-</a></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="name[]" /></td>


    <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="http://" /></td>
    <td><a class="sort">|||</a></td>
    <td>
        <textarea id="editor"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When a button is clicked it clones the above HTML table row and inserts it as a new row into the DOM with this JS/jQuery `.clone(true)`...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#add-row').on('click', function() {
        var row = $('.empty-row.screen-reader-text').clone(true);
        row.removeClass('empty-row screen-reader-text');
        row.insertBefore('#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

---

My problem

I need to take the textarea from the HTML above with ID `editor`...

```
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

And I need to run this JavaScript to turn it into a WYSIWYG editor in WordPress where the value below for `id` is a unique value for each new row/editor added to the DOM...

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, id);
```

Because the HTML row is cloned with `clone(true)` it copies over the same exact editor instance from the previous row since I am unable to set and initiate a new editor uysing a unique ID.

So how could I reproduce all this functionality while allowing my new row that is added to the DOM to have a custom ID value and thn run `tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, id);` on that new ID after the new row is added to DOM?

Comment: atleast show some manners to comment on the answer, whether it worked for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to remove the duplicate ID after the clone and use a class name insted of it. TinyMCE wont create the editor, if the ID is duplicate.

```
$(".screen-reader-text").clone().find("textarea").removeAttr("id").addClass("editor");
```

Then the editor binding code will be,

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, ".editor");
```

Comment: Sorry I just got to test.  I had to end up adding a unique ID to each new editor.  Reason being if I did it with a shared class, the previous editors would quit working when a new one is added.  I will post my solution for others as my search resulted in many people trying to accomplish this with no luck but I have it working now.  Thanks for the answer